# Iterating over JSON ptree in boost

Tags: c++, json, boost

I need some help when iterating over JSON ptree in boost.  Here's the structure.

```
{"drives": [{"busy": false, "eof": false, "density": 88 }]}
```

What I want to do is to print the key and value eg.  busy = false.  I've tried the code below but there is no output.

```
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("drives"))
{
    cout << v.first << endl; // does not work
    cout << v.second.data() << endl; // does not work
    cout << v.second.get<string>("busy"); // works
}
```

So how do I print the key?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sorry I have no constructive comment, but after using property_tree with JSON and XML I really think you better off with a framework that was written for reading JSON (or xml) and not a framework that was written in order to generalize reading from JSON / XML and ini.

Answer (score 0):

I went through some old code and I found the way

```
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("drives"))
{
   for(auto iter = v.second.begin(); iter!= v.second.end(); ++iter)
   {
       std::cout << iter->first << " : " << iter->second.get_value<std::string>() << std::endl;
   }

}
```

You only need to iterate over "drives" if you have more than one "drives", and in your json example you don't have.

In your code you try to print v.first and v.data() but those two doesn't hold the data you think they hold.

v.first supposed to hold the key name of *"KeyName"*:{"busy": false, "eof": false, "density": 88 }

which doesn't exists because this value is part of an array.

the v.data() (If I'm not mistaken) holds the key:value which is an inner presentation and cannot be printed this way.

I really think you should try using a different framework for JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Any ideas which framework is better.  I was thinking of using jsoncpp.

Comment: Sorry I don't have input on JSON frameworks, when I used property_tree to read JSON it had a bug on ubuntu, instead of moving to a framework I tried using property_tree with XML... and later I moved to rapid_xml (because I already had too many xml files to go back to JSON), on the bottom of http://www.json.org/ you have other alternatives. but AFAIK jsoncpp is a good solid one.